# why can't I add a method to window.external object in Internet Explorer but working on other browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, external

The following **javascript** code is working on both Chrome and Firefox but not working on Internet Explorer.

```
window.external.vals = function(){alert("asdf");}
```

I have tried on the respective console, every other browser is working appropriately but IE throws the following error

**"Object doesn't support this property or method"**

Any idea ?

Comment: It's a built in feature of Internet Explorer, and probably isn't modifiable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535246(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Additional IE browser functionalities are mapped through the `window.external` in IE. For other browsers it is just another object in the window.

You can however add any method to `window.external` by using IE automation server. At the end of the day the method is going to be written as a windows binary - not as a javascript method.

But you can call this method inside Javascript and use what it returns or invoke the services it offer.

[This](http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=22&part=2) article shows how you can extend the IE external object in Delphi. But you can convert this code to C# since it is all about COM interfaces.